# File not found found exception - but I know it's there

Tags: java

I keep getting a "File not found exception", but I know it's there! `File file = new File("C:\\A-small-practice.in");` is able to find the file fine, but when I try to use `FileInputStream` it returns an exception.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       File file = new File("C:\\A-small-practice.in");
       System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath()); //prints C:\A-small-practice.in

       FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it throwing a file-not-found exception?

Comment: Do you have permissions to access and open files right in C:\ root?

Comment: does this file really exists and readable? please check siwht exists() and isReadable() os something...

Comment: @galuano1 yess it is throwing a file-not-found exception for FileInputStream, but NOT for File file = new File()

Comment: Some problems about this: your file name is incorrect, it could have a file extension and be "A-small-practice.in.txt" or similar.

Comment: file.getAbsolutePath() returns C:\A-small-practice.in

Comment: Does it print prints C:\A-small-practice.in or prints C:\\A-small-practice.in @absolutePath

Comment: @kitten_bro Yes, because that's the absolute path name you've given to your file. Check the real name of your file in your sistem using a explorer (right click on your file, properties, the complete file name with extensions and all. That's the String you should pass to your `new File(String s);` statement.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza the real name of the file in my system is A-small-practice.in , no hidden extensions. I launched eclipse as an administrator

Comment: @kitten_bro Instead of using `getAbsolutePath()` try using `getCanonicalPath()`. Are these the same?

Comment: @nybbler when I try to use getCanonicalPath(), I get IOException

Comment: @mlishn It prints C:\A-small-practice.in

Comment: Make sure there is no program using the file before running your java program. To make a test, make a copy of the file and try to open it.

Comment: @kitten_bro That could happen due to filesystem queries `getCanonicalPath()` does that `getAbsolutePath()` does not do. Sounds like a permissions issue on the file, or something has it locked maybe?

Comment: @nybbler How can I resolve a permission issue? I am using eclipse on win7

Comment: @kitten_bro I would try copying the file to the same location as your  project (ie: in your classpath) and open it from there as a first test. Then you can compare permission differences between the two locations

Comment: @nybbler I get the same exception. I am certain that this file is not being used by any other program

Comment: @kitten_bro If it's within your classpath now, can you load it using `Class.getResource(String name)`?  If not, something is really awry or it's not where you think it is

Comment: Please do not use the comment section as an interactive debugging session.

Answer (score 2):

The [**File**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html) has some methods that can help you.

```
boolean canExecute();
boolean canRead();
boolean canWrite();
boolean exists();
boolean isFile();
boolean isDirectory();
boolean isAbsolute()
```

For example, you could check for: exists() && isFile() && canRead() and print a better error-message depending on the reason why you cant read the file.

Comment: Check if there is a hidden extension

Answer (score 0):

When you write :

```
   File file = new File("C:\\A-small-practice.in");
```

A file will be made if one dosen't exist, so there will be no reason for
you the get an exception when call file.getAbsolutePath()).

However if the file didn't exist it will throw a file not found exception,
once you try to open an input stream for a non existing file.
So my suggestion is try calling .exsits(). To see if the file do exist.

Also the java documenation for the file not found exception says the following :
"It will also be thrown by these constructors if the file does exist but for some reason is inaccessible".
So perhaps you should share some info on the file itself.

Comment: Hi oopsi,
I keep the file at C:\A-small-practice.in. I have checked the permissions which should be fine (read/write for everyone/system)

Comment: Have you tried to put other files in the same directory but with a different extension? maybe it's the .in file that is causing the problem.

Comment: Yes I am, running as administrator. I have set all permissions on my file.

Comment: Try placing a file in the project folder. say "simple.txt". Than write File file = new File("simple.txt");